# How to find the common elements of a string but not in the right order in Python?

Tags: python, string, indexing

Suppose there are two strings:

```
str1 = "15323"
str2 = "12314"
```

How can I find the indexes of the numbers in both strings that are not in the same order based on one of the strings? 
Expected:

```
[3, 4] # the numbers in str1 that are in str2 but not in the exact place of str2: 2 and 3
"15323"
    ^^
"12314"
  ^^
```

Another example since I can't really explain it:

```
str1 = "3546"
str2 = "1346"
```

Expected:

```
[0] # only "3" is in str1 AND str2 and it does not have the same index as the "3" in str2

"3546"
"3" in "3546" appears in str2 and it does not have the same index
"5" in "3546" does not appear in str2
"4" in "3546" appears in str1 but has the same index as the "4" in str2
"6" in "3546" appears in str1 but has the same index as the "6" in str2
```

I have tried some code to find the common elements in two strings, but I can't quite wrap my head around duplicates. I would not like to import any modules, and thank you in advance.

```
result = []
for string in str1:
  if string in str2:
    if str1.index(string) != str2.index(string):
      result.append(str1.index(string))
```

Comment: Double check your second example. You have there "35" and "13", and the expected is `[0]`? why?

Comment: The expected is [0] because there is a `list` named `result` that has all the indexes of the substrings that meet the criteria above. In this case, `str1[0]` is `"3"` and that meets the criteria. Sorry if my wording of the problem isn't great, I'm not great at English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficient membership test you can convert `str2` to a set, and enumerate a zipped sequence of `str1` and `str2`, and only output indices where the corresponding characters aren't equal and the one in `str1` is in the set:

```
s = set(str2)
[i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)) if a != b and a in s]
```

so that given:

```
str1 = "15323"
str2 = "12314"
```

the expression would return:

```
[3, 4]
```

and that given:

```
str1 = "3546"
str2 = "1346"
```

it would return:

```
[0]
```

Comment: Indexes are a concern here. I do not think `set` is the best and efficient approach for this question

Comment: No, the `if i in str2:` in your code for example unnecessarily makes the solution of *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity instead of *O(n)*, which can be achieved with a set conversion upfront.

Comment: Exactly how? `if i in str2:` is functionally exactly the same as `s = set(str2)` and `if i in s:`, except the latter is more efficient in a loop. The `in` operator doesn't care if `str2` has duplicates. BTW `str2` does have duplicates as shown in the OP's first example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` and not `index` to find index. `index` will return the first occurrence of the value in the string.

Refined code

```
result = []
for idx,i in enumerate(str1):
    if i in str2:
        if str2[idx]!=i:      
            result.append(idx)
```